# How to read/write a file in Meteor-Cordova?

Tags: cordova, meteor, cordova-plugins

After days of useless research (I've tried all possible tutorials and code snippets on the Internet, Github, SO etc.) I'm desperately looking for a way to use Cordova file plugin to:

- read a text / json file
- write a text file

In most of my attemps I get fileErrror error codes 1 and 5.
Also, I'm not sure whether I should create a directory assets, or public or whatever.

I'm using Crosswalk package.
An example of code I've tried out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33156697/filesystem-api-cordova-file-is-created-but-cant-be-written

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `window.requestFileSystem()`, try using `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL()`. That worked for me.

Full explanation here: [FileError {code: 5} trying to use absolute file paths with Meteor 1.4 Cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38800845/fileerror-code-5-trying-to-use-absolute-file-paths-with-meteor-1-4-cordova)

Example code here: https://github.com/meonkeys/cordova-file-test/tree/solution