# FileError {code: 5} trying to use absolute file paths with Meteor 1.4 Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, meteor

I'm trying to use Meteor 1.4 with Cordova (mobile support) to read files on my android phone.

I've got a small [Meteor app](https://github.com/meonkeys/cordova-file-test) running on my phone (via `meteor run android-device`). I have also created a small text file in the app's private storage using `adb shell` and [`run-as`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558353/how-can-one-pull-the-private-data-of-ones-own-android-app).

I can read the file if I call `getFile('a')`, but I can't find any way to use `cordova.file.dataDirectory` (even with `WebAppLocalServer.localFileSystemUrl`) as [recommended in the Meteor guide](https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#accessing-local-files). I get `FileError {code: 5}` ([ENCODING_ERR](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file#list-of-error-codes-and-meanings)).

Here's the JS console output from the Chrome inspector when I click the button in [my app](https://github.com/meonkeys/cordova-file-test):

[image: meteor app in chrome inspector throwing FileError code 5]

- This repros on both Android 5 and 6.
- My dev environment is 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
- App Info for my app reports it has these permissions:

  - modify or delete the contents of your SD card
  - read the contents of your SD card
- The app uses the [cordova file plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/) [version 4.2.0](https://github.com/meonkeys/cordova-file-test/blob/master/.meteor/cordova-plugins).
- Dup? [How to read/write a file in Meteor-Cordova?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33189234/how-to-read-write-a-file-in-meteor-cordova)
- This *does* work in the `chrome://inspect` console via USB debugging: `HTTP.call('GET', 'http://localhost:12640/local-filesystem/data/user/0/com.adammonsen.app/files/a', {}, function (e,r) {console.error(e); console.log(r)});`

  - output is `Object {statusCode: 200, content: "in external dir↵", headers: Object, data: null}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. The trick is to use `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL()` to get at the filesystem. Here's how to get at a file on external storage. My original question was about app-private storage. If you're looking for that, just use the `cordova.file.dataDirectory` instead of `cordova.file.externalDataDirectory`.

```
function reportError(err) {
  console.error(err);
}

function readFile(file) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function() {
    console.log('read file! contents: ' + this.result);
  };
  reader.readAsText(file);
}

function processFileEntry(fileEntry) {
  fileEntry.file(file => {
    readFile(file);
  }, reportError);
}

Template.hello.events({
  'click button'(event, instance) {
    // increment the counter when button is clicked
    instance.counter.set(instance.counter.get() + 1);

    if (Meteor.isCordova) {
      // aaaaaand do some other stuff
      const path = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory + 'a';
      window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path, fileEntry => {
        console.log('fileEntry: ', fileEntry);
        processFileEntry(fileEntry);
      }, reportError);
    }
  },
});
```

See https://github.com/meonkeys/cordova-file-test/tree/solution for a full working example and instructions.

Make sure `AndroidExtraFilesystems` includes `files-external`. I used this line in my `mobile-config.js`:

```
App.setPreference('AndroidExtraFilesystems', 'files,files-external');
```

I'd love to understand the difference between the APIs, but for now I'm just happy I found something that works reliably.